# How to build an bulk sms sender or voip server?

Tags: sms, voip, sms-gateway

I want to know how can I build my own Sms service provider? 
In another say; What is needed to have a system to inject sms messages to the mobile network systems freely or is it possible at all?

with VoIP server we can do voice and video and text messaging through internet; but what about from internet to the land line or mobile network?

How Skype, smartvoip, etc. do this? 
Please give me a direction that I could go through.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of interface to the Mobile network to make this work. Your choices include:

- build a system with a GSM/UMTS card or phone which you control to send SMS messages into the network. This will need a valid SIM and contract (and the small print may say that you are not allowed to use it to provide an IP to SMS service to others). If you google 'Asterix SMS Gateway' you can find several open source examples. You could also look at http://www.kannel.org/overview.shtml, although I am not sure how actively this is being maintained these days.
- Build a front end for your SMS service and use an existing back end SMS service in whatever your target market is - i.e. connect directly to your local operators SMSC, most likely using SMPP protocol. This assumes the operator provides this service in your target network/market.
- Use an SMS aggregator service such as MBlox or Clickatell